# Getting incorrect output for pow function typecasted in int for 5,11,15... and so on raised to 2

Tags: c

other number number raised to 2 are giving correct answer but 5,11,15... are showing 1 number less than the correct answer.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<math.h>
int main(){ 
int side;
printf("Enter side value \n");
scanf("%d", &side);
printf("The area is %d", (int) pow(side,2.0));
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What do you get when you don't cast to `int`? I assume you get a tiny bit less than you expect. I've added a link to a queston where issues with floating point math are described in more detail.

Comment: `pow(side, 2.0)` is the same as `side * side`, except that the latter doesn't have spurious rounding errors.

Comment: You should avoid using floating point function when dealing with integers.

Comment: If you are using math functions on integers they should be rounded, not truncated. Casting truncates. So `printf("The area is %d", (int)round(pow(side,2.0)));`